# How to execute an array of tasks sequentially?

Tags: f#, task, mutable

I have the following code that I want to review

```ml
printfn "calling openai embeddings API"
let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ()
sw.Start ()
let embs : MyRedis.RedisEmbedding array = 
    docs 
    |> MyOpenAI.rebuild2EmbeddingsSlow             
    
    // here the part of the code to be defined and reviewed
    
sw.Stop ()
printfn "Artificially slowed down to %f" (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
```

The goal of the code is to show the timing of the sequential execution of an array of tasks in the log and possibly also to guarantee that the execution is sequential and not parallel, as it would be, I think, with a simpler `Task.WhenAll`.

Though I 've had to introduce a `mutable` accumulator because `Task.WhenAll` returns a `Task` that is not yet executed and I was not able to insert the timing part within it.

Also, something like

```ml
    |> Array.fold (fun s t -> 
        printfn "slow down - intermediate elapsed start %f " (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
        let! e1 = t
        printfn "intermediate elapsed end %f " (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
        Array.concat [| e1; s |]
    )
```

would not compile because of the `let!`

But I want to be sure that the following code is F# idiomatic and that the usage of a `mutable` keyword is unavoidable.

```ml
printfn "calling openai embeddings API"
let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ()
sw.Start ()
let embs : MyRedis.RedisEmbedding array = 
    docs 
    |> MyOpenAI.rebuild2EmbeddingsSlow             
    |> Array.fold (fun s t -> 
        let mutable acc = [||]
        printfn "slow down - intermediate elapsed start %f " (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
        task {
            let! e1 = t
            acc <- Array.append e1 s
        } |> Task.WaitAll
        printfn "intermediate elapsed end %f " (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
        acc
        ) 
        [| |]
sw.Stop ()
printfn "Artificially slowed down to %f" (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
```

I think that the `let!` binding cannot be used directly inside the `Array.fold` function as it is outside the computation expression, hence the code does indeed use a `mutable` variable acc correctly within the `Array.fold` function and the `mutable` variable is necessary to accumulate the embeddings in the array.

Is that agreeable? Is the code F# idiomatic?

Comment: This looks complicated, but I think you're mainly trying to run an array of tasks sequentially, right? Note that tasks start running as soon as they are created, so they can't really be run in sequence. You can await them sequentially, but you can't really execute them in sequence if they already exist.

Comment: @BrianBerns good point, the answer could be that I should rather use the F# cold async instead of the C# hot task...

Comment: In that case, you can use `Async.Sequential` to run your array of asyncs sequentially.

Comment: it is exactly what I am trying now!

Comment: @BrianBerns you could write this as an answer, I have tried and it seems ok (btw I don't understand why my overall time is almost always the same, it looks like on OpenAI side they are "reacting" to the calls in some "smart" way...). You should clarify if I can do return! openAIClient.GetEmbeddingsAsync (model, embeddingOptions) |> Async.AwaitTask inside an |> Array.map followed by an Async.Parallel that would produce each Async<Response<Embeddings> array> batch of size N and then those batches will go in |> Async.Sequential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of creating an array of F# asyncs from underlying .NET tasks, and then executing them sequentially.

To start with, I wrote a dummy function that mimics a call to OpenAI's API:

```ml
let openAiTask i =
    task {
        do! Task.Delay(1000)
        return! Task.FromResult i
    }
```

Then I created a batch of F# async calls to the API:

```ml
let asyncs =
    let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    [| 1..10 |]
        |> Array.map (fun i ->
            async {
                printfn "%A" sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
                return! openAiTask i |> Async.AwaitTask
            })
```

Now I can execute the async calls sequentially whenever I want:

```ml
let results =
    Async.Sequential asyncs
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
printfn "%A" results
```

Note that none of the API calls occur until I explicitly run them. Output is something like:

```
0.0238377
1.0503682
2.0602829
3.0719534
4.0832107
5.0838953
6.0951127
7.1090538
8.1239493
9.1347231
[|1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9; 10|]
```

Comment: Minor note: actually I have an array of array of calls, so - unlike python `.apply(lambda: ...` that is fully sequential in requesting the embeddings 1 by 1 - my code has a real parallelism of blocks of n calls - to benefit at max from the rate limit - and then I have to sequentially run those blocks of parallel calls. Yeah of course nothing changes from the point of view of your answer, it remains the same, I know. Also, I've noticed that openAiTask - even though it is Task, not Async- is not started  - maybe obvious, but imo crucial - **till i is given** or the function is partially applied.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of avoiding the `mutable` variable, I've found the following solution

```
printfn "calling openai embeddings API"
let sw = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch ()
sw.Start ()
let embs_timings_task : Task<(MyRedis.RedisEmbedding array) array> = 
    docs 
    |> MyOpenAI.rebuild2EmbeddingsSlow             
    // be kind: fold the async workflows with sequential composition
    |> Array.fold (fun s t -> 
        let sequential = 
            task {
            let curr_start = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
            printfn "intermediate elapsed start %f " curr_start
            let! acc = s 
            let acc = acc |> Array.last
            let! e = t
            let curr_end = sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
            printfn "intermediate elapsed end %f " curr_end
            return Array.append acc e
            } 
            |> Task.WhenAll
        // the following is needed to make all the steps sequential instead of parallel
        sequential |> Task.WaitAll
        sequential               ) 
        (Task.FromResult [|[| |] |])
let! embs_timings_arr = embs_timings_task
let embs = embs_timings_arr |> Array.last
sw.Stop ()
printfn "Artificially slowed down to %f" (sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
```

where the most important thing is the **internal** `sequential |> Task.WaitAll` which is **key** to make all the steps **sequential** instead of **parallel**.

The rest is simply a transformation from a `Task.WaitAll` *wrapper* to an *external*  `Task.WhenAll` wrapper, which avoids the need of a `mutable` but implies an `array` of results, the `last` one being the only relevant since the computation is intended to be sequential.

Comment: However, in this case, using a mutable variable acc to accumulate the results within the Array.fold function provides a clear and straightforward solution. so I don't think it's worth transforming the code to avoid that mutable acc because imho the code would be less readable and not necessarily more F# idiomatic.

Comment: I've kept this answer for historical tracking purposes, but I've already switched from using the hot Task in C# to utilizing the cold Async in F#. Please refer to this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76445536/is-a-mutable-variable-needed-in-this-case#comment134796627_76445536 e